# Ant condition block

Tags: ant

I have an ant condition like this:

```
   <condition property="create_stub">
    <and>
      <available file="${create_stub_command_file}" property="stub_script.present" />
      <isset property="packaged_stub_file"/>
    </and>
   </condition>
```

My understanding is: If `create_stub_command_file` is present then set `stub_script.present=true`. But I am not sure about

```
<isset property="packaged_stub_file"/>
```

What is this doing? And how does it change the overall condition. i.e In which case would the condition block evaluate to true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equivolent pseudo code:

```
if (File($create_stub_command_file).exists) then
   property["stub_script.present"] := true
end 

if (File($create_stub_command_file).exists AND property["property["stub_script.present"] != NULL) then
   property["create_stub"] := true
end
```

Forgive any errors... I find condition blocks tricky and they need lots of testing. You're best advised to keep them simple. ANT is not a programming language.

Answer (score 1):

A slight mistake?

```
<condition property="create_stub">
    <and>
       <available file="${create_stub_command_file}" property="stub_script.present" />
       <isset property="packaged_stub_file"/>
    </and>
</condition>
```

I don't believe that `property="stub_script.present"` is doing anything. It should be:

```
<condition property="create_stub">
    <and>
       <available file="${create_stub_command_file}"/>
       <isset property="packaged_stub_file"/>
    </and>
</condition>
```

All that condition statement is doing is setting a property called `create_stub`. It will set the property if both a file or directory called whatever `{$create_stub_command_file}` exists, and if the property `packaged_stuf_file` is set to any value. The property `packaged_stub_file` can be set to `false`, to a null string, to `true`, to `YES! YES! YES!` or to anything, as long as it is set.

So now you can use this property as a *test* for a target:

```
<target name="package_stub"
    if="create_stub">
    <blah...blah...blah/>
    <yadda...yadda...yadda/>
</target>
```

This target, `package_stub` will only execute if the property `package_stub` is set. And it will only be set if that `<condition>` above is true.

That `<condition>` statement should be outside of any targets, so it will be executed first before any targets are executed.